# Use a LLVM compiled version of Qt

Tags: qt, llvm

I've seen some mkspec for mac or linux using llvm.

Does anyone use an llvm compiled version of Qt ? Or llvm on their Qt Projects ? does it speed up compilation times ? Is your project faster ?

Comment: Here is a fresh blog post from Qt : http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/10/19/qt-creator-and-clang/ which is quite interesting. so It's about clang :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true - Qt can be compiled via llvm-gcc since version 1.9. clang is currently "almost" able to compile Qt fully. Note that the code of Qt is not sometimes standard-compliant :)

Answer (score 3):

According to [this bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=5881) compiling Qt using LLVM is not yet possible.